# Is it possible to override std::istream read method?

Tags: c++

I want to use std::istream to read data from a given class which only provides 2 methods:

```
// Returns a byte from the stream (consuming it)
uint8_t getChar(OwnIOStream stream);
// Makes the passed pointer point to the data in the stream
bool getCharBlockPtr(OwnIOStream stream, uint8_t** buffer, uin32_t maxSize, uint32_t* size);
```

I first thought of inheriting from stream_buf and implement the underflow method using the getChar() method. However I would like to use the getCharBlockPtr() instead to avoid copies of data (I assume calling underflow for each read byte will decrease the performance). The problem is that I need to know in advance the quantity of bytes I want to read each time. This is why I was thinking whether it would be possible to override the read method of istream.

Using boost is not an option.

Comment: Is it an option to use an internal buffer in your `streambuf` implementation and fill it with `getCharBlockPtr` in `underflow()`?

Comment: No, I want to avoid copies of data. I need to use directly the buffer provided by getCharBlockPtr (i.e. putting the content directly into a file without extra copies).

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that most classes from the standard C++ library are not meant to be derived. The exception here is the `streambuf` class which is intended to be the low level interface between an IO capable *object* and a C++ `stream`.

So the *standard* way here would be to build a custom `streambuf` calling `getChar` or better `getCharBlockPtr` that would allow buffering. Jerry's answer explains how to do it.

But it looks like you have special requirement here:

- you know at a higher level the number of bytes you want to read
- you are in a performance critical operation and want to avoid buffer copies if possible - but this last point should be reviewed after profiling...

Then, asking for the full power of a C++ stream may not be the way to go. Building a custom class that would only implement the methods of a `istream` that you need to call, as well as few extractors would still give a nice code at high level and could give a more optimized code at low level.

But you and only you can know:

- whether your higher level code requires a C++ stream - then a custom class is not an option and you will have to use a custom streambuf
- whether you could directly give the expected size to the streambuf from the calling code as a hint. More or less:

  ```
  class OwnStreamBuf: public std::streambuf {
      ...
      void sizehint(size_t hint) { /* size for next read access */
         this->hint = hint
      }
      int_type underflow() {
          ...
          cr = getCharBlockPtr(stream, buffer, hint, size); /* use hint as maxSize */
          ...
      }
  }
  ...
  OwnStreamBuf buf(...);
  class OwnIStream: public istream ...
  OwnIStream is(buf)
  ...
  buf.sizehint(n)
  is >> special_obj;
  ...
  ```
- whether you only need a handful of extractors and a custom class will be simpler to build from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving from streambuf is a perfectly valid option.

Whether you need to do much (if any) more than override `underflow` depends. If `OwnIOStream` is already buffering data, then you might get adequate performance from just doing that. I'd start by doing that, and seeing how things go.

The next obvious step would be to use `getCharBlockPtr`. A `streambuf` has a `setg` that you use to set the pointers to the beginning, current position, and end of the buffer. At least if I'm interpreting things correctly, you'd call `getCharBlockPtr` and get the beginning and end. You'd then call `setg` to set the beginning and current positions to the beginning, and the end to the end. From there, the streambuf *should* be able to read data directly from the buffer. When it runs out, it'll call `underflow`, and you'll need to get more data again.

One note: it doesn't look like `OwnIOStream` supports a putback area, which streams normally do expect to support. Getting this to work correctly (especially putting back a character when at the beginning of a buffer) may be somewhat non-trivial to support correctly.

Comment: After your comment, I could find a [tutorial](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf) to subclass streambuf. As soon as you implement an internal buffer, the putback area can just use it.

Comment: Yes, as soon as *you* ceate a buffer, it can be used. The point here was to *use* the existing buffer rather than creating another. Normally, when you create a buffer, you leave some space at the beginning for the putback area--but if you're using an existing buffer that didn't leave space for a putback area, it can be rather more difficult.

Comment: OwnIOStream may be already buffering data, although I do not have access to its internal code. My concern here is that if I implement underflow reading a byte each time it is called using the getChar method provided by OwnIOStream the performance may be quite bad. This is why I wanted to use getCharBlockPtr instead. The problem I find is that I do not know how many bytes the istream is going to request and I do not want to make an extra copy.